# Serial port to cisco switch no input or output showing

Tags: linux, cisco

I was able to console into Cisco switches fine until this morning using:

```
cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 9600
```

But as of this morning, it shows connected, but no output or input is displayed.

Here are the the things I have tried:

- Reboot / full system shutdown
- Different console cable
- Different serial port ttyUSB1 (using a second cable) and different
  physical port on my laptop
- Tested the cable / switch from a Windows box with putty and it works fine
- Tried screen, minicom, putty for Linux, termius, GTKTerm - all of
  them do the same thing
- Checked the perms on the ports:

  crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Feb  6 11:01 /dev/ttyUSB0
- GTKTerm lets you change the settings individually. I made sure they
  are all set to the cisco recommended settings 9600 8n1.
- Verified I an a member of the dialout group
- Also tried:

  sudo cu -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 9600

I am at a loss as to what could have happened. I can't even imagine having to use a windows laptop to connect to devices, but we have a huge project kicking off tomorrow and I must be able to console into the switches.

### Update - Though I do not understand it, for some reason, it is just a couple of switches that it doesn't work on. What made this so hard to troubleshoot is that with the same cable connected to a Windows laptop, I could console in with putty. The solution for now I am calling some weird incompatibility with Cisco 9300's. All of the 9500's I had to configure today worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Just for clarity: does this happen with multiple switches? Were you able to try rebooting the switch while console is connected? Please [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/734574/edit) your question to add new info instead of responding in a comment.

Comment: Connect the RS232 port's transmit pin to its receive pin and see if your keystrokes in the terminal program appear on your screen.  If they do, then your keystrokes are successfully being transmitted into the RS232 cable (and characters coming in from the cable are successfully being shown on your screen), and you can pursue the RS232 cable and conditions on the switch's port.  If they don't, then the issue is most likely in your USB adapter, the drivers for the USB/tty device, or the settings of your RS232 program (`cu`, `minicom`, etc.).